# scatterplot regression line lty command is not being recognized

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

Ive been using the scatterplot command from the Car package to create a plot of my data and I am trying to refine the image for publication.  Thus it needs to be in black and white which means I need to change the colored lines to a solid and dashed line.  I thought that `lty` would be the proper command to do this.  Within the help of scatterplot, it has a function called `by.groups` and I think that this is somehow interfering with the lty = c(1,2) or lty = 1:2 idea that I used with the `legend` part of the code.  I don't know how to do this in ggplot so suggestions there would be appreciated if people are so inclined.

here's some example data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L), .Label = c("F07001", "F07002", "F07003", 
"F07004", "F07005", "F07006", "F07008", "F07009", "F07010", "F07011", 
"F07014", "F07015", "F07017", "F07018", "F07019", "F07020", "F07021", 
"F07022", "F07023", "F07024", "F10001", "F10004", "F10008", "F10009", 
"F10010", "F10012", "F10013", "F98015", "M07007", "M07012", "M07013", 
"M07016", "M10007", "M10011", "M10015"), class = "factor"), Season = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("SUM", "WIN"
), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("day", "night"), class = "factor"), 
    Repro = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("f", "fc", "m"), class = "factor"), Comp1 = c(-0.524557195, 
    -0.794214153, -0.408247216, -0.621285004, -0.238828585, 0.976634392, 
    -0.202405922, -0.633821539, -0.306163898, -0.302261589, 1.218779672
    ), ln1wr = c(0.833126490613386, 0.824526258616325, 0.990730077688989, 
    0.981816265754353, 0.933462450382474, 1.446048015519, 1.13253050687157, 
    1.1349442179155, 1.14965388471562, 1.14879830358128, 1.14055365645628
    )), .Names = c("ID", "Season", "Time", "Repro", "Comp1", 
"ln1wr"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 
223L, 224L, 225L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code Ive written thus far:

```
par(bty="l",las=1)
scatterplot(Comp1~ln1wr|Season, moose,
            xlab = "Wolf risk", ylab = "Principal component 1",
            labels= row.names(moose),
            by.groups=TRUE, smooth=FALSE, boxplots=FALSE,
            grid=FALSE, lty = 1:2,
            legend.plot=FALSE)
legend("bottomright", title="Season",
       legend=levels(moose$Season), bty="n",
       pch=1:2, col=1:2, lty=c(1,2))
```

Comment: I've looked into the `scatterplot` code and I'm fairly sure you can't get what you want without either (1) hacking the code (although it's a very minor hack or (2) moving to ggplot. Will post an answer later if I get a chance/someone else doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something in lattice:

```
 xyplot(Comp1~ln1wr, 
        data=moose,
        groups=Season,
        xlab = "Wolf risk", ylab = "Principal component 1",
        par.settings=list(superpose.symbol=list(pch=1:2, col=1),
                          superpose.line=list(lty=1:2, col=1)),
        panel = function(x, y, ...) {
          panel.superpose(x, y, ...,
                          panel.groups = function(x,y, col, col.symbol, lty, ...) {
                            panel.xyplot(x, y, col=col.symbol, ...)
                            panel.abline(lm(y~x), col.line=col.symbol, lty=lty)
                          }
          )
        },
        auto.key=list(title='Season', space='inside', 
                      #text=c('Summer', 'Winter'),
                      lines=TRUE)
 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry @BenBolker, I started to work on this before seeing your comment:

Yes, it looks like hacking the `scatterplot.default` function would be a way to solve this.

Since it's a non-exported function, this is a bit tricky, but here 'tis

```
# Get function and create copy to edit:
mySP <- car:::scatterplot.default

# Change part of function that plots lines to index lty by i
body(mySP)[[34]][[4]][[4]][[3]][[3]][[3]] <- 
  quote(reg(reg.line, .x[subs], .y[subs], lty = lty[i], lwd = lwd, log.x = logged("x"), 
    log.y = logged("y"), col = col[i]))

# Assign altered function back to package namespace
assignInNamespace("scatterplot.default", mySP, "car")
```

Now your code should yield one solid and one dashed line.

Comment: don't apologize -- you saved me the trouble!  It would be worth contacting the maintainer (John Fox) about this, as it's a trivial fix in the code ...

Comment: @BenBolker I did contact John Fox and this is what he said: "you can't do it with scatterplot(), at least without modifying the program. In particular, although when plotting by groups you can change the symbols and colours for the groups, you cannot change the line types. Setting lty (as explained in ?scatterplot) controls the line type for the LS lines. Use plot() to get the graph that you want. You'll have more control over the various aspects of the graph. Alternatively, you could distinguish the groups by using, say, black and gray."

Comment: @BenBarnes Thanks!  I think I might try learning lattice or ggplot instead of hacking into the code.  That kind of knowledge is so far beyond my skills to be able to replicate and even know when I would need to do that in the future!

Comment: @Kerry, learning `lattice` and/or `ggplot2` is definitely a good idea, and not just for this issue! They are both excellent graphics packages. And thanks for contacting John Fox.